# Erro em programa c# com vetores

Tags: c#

Eu estou tendo um problema na linha 18 desse código que diz:"Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento do tipo "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" em ConsoleApp19.exe
O índice estava fora dos limites da matriz.

Como resolver?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp19
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] x = new int[n];
            int contPar = 0, maior = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i<= x.Length; i++)
            {
                x[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if(x[i]%2 == 0)
                {
                    contPar++;
                }
                if(x[i] > maior)
                {
                    maior = x[i];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("O maior número é {0}", maior);
            Console.WriteLine("Existem {0} n°s pares", contPar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vetores iniciam a partir do indice zero. O problema está no cabeçalho do for: `(int i = 0; i< x.Length; i++)`

Answer (score 2):

Duas coisas que você tem que levar em conta.

- Vetores em *C#* tem como primeiro índice o zero.
- Vetores em *C#* tem como último índice `Length - 1`.

---

Ciente disso:

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] x = new int[n];
        int contPar = 0, maior = 0;


        //As únicas modificações no seu código i começa em 0 e comparação entre
        // i e x.Length deixa de ser '<='  e passe a ser '<'
        // o que equivaleria i <= x.Length - 1
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            x[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(x[i]%2 == 0)
            {
                contPar++;
            }
            if(x[i] > maior)
            {
                maior = x[i];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("O maior número é {0}", maior);
        Console.WriteLine("Existem {0} n°s pares", contPar);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Os índices do vetor vão de 0 a `n-1`, sendo `n` o tamanho.
Portanto, `int[] vetor = new int[3];` terá os itens `vetor[0]`, `vetor[1]` e `vetor[2]`

Seu `for` vai de 1 a `x.Length`, então quando chegar no último valor, o `x[n]` vai procurar um índice que não existe no vetor.